# Spark: More Executors in one machine, longer duration time for each Task

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When I run LogisticRegression in Spark, I found a stage is special, as the number of executors increases, the average task processing time becomes longer, why it could happen?

### Environment:

- All servers are local, no cloud.
- Server 1: 6 cores 10g memory (**Spark master**, HDFS master, HDFS slave).
- Server 2: 6 cores 10g memory (HDFS slave).
- Server 3: 6 cores 10g memory (**Spark slave**, HDFS slave).
- Deploy in Spark standalone mode.
- Input file size: Large enough, it can meet the requirements of parallelism. Spark will read the file from HDFS.
- **All the workloads have the same input file.**

You can see that only server3 will participate in the calculation(Only it will become Spark worker).

### Special stage DAG

[image]

### 1 core 1g memory

```
spark-submit --executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 1g --total-executor-cores 1 ....
```

**mid-task duration: 1s**

[image]

### 2 core 2g memory

```
spark-submit --executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 1g --total-executor-cores 2 ....
```

**mid-task duration: 2s**

[image]

### 3 core 3g memory

```
spark-submit --executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 1g --total-executor-cores 3 ....
```

**mid-task duration: 2s**

[image]

### 4 core 4g memory

```
spark-submit --executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 1g --total-executor-cores 4 ....
```

**mid-task duration: 3s**

[image]

### 5 core 5g memory

```
spark-submit --executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 1g --total-executor-cores 5 ....
```

**mid-task duration: 3s**
[image]

As can be seen from the above figure, the more executors on a machine will cause the longer the average running time of a single task. May I ask why this could happen, and I had not seen the executor had disk spill, the memory should be sufficient.

**Note: Only this stage will produce this phenomenon, other stages did not have this problem.**

Comment: HDFS and no S3 I presume?

Comment: Only HDFS in my local cluster.

Comment: Assumed so but important to mentiopn